# Remove a header from POST request in Nuxt 3

Tags: request, header, fetch-api, nuxt3, nitro

I am trying to call an external API that appears to dislike my Origin header of http://localhost:3000 etc. which is fine, makes sense. But for testing purposes I just need to test that I can get the info back I need to move foreward on a project.

The API in question is referred to [in this support comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/315313/azure-app-registration-causing-the-following-error?page=1#answers) which suggests removing the Origin header should do the trick:

How can I do that in Nuxt 3 using the $fetch API or perhaps a config/middleware/plugin thing? I've been searching for a while and I cannot find anyone trying to do the same, so I'm not sure if it's even possible. NOTE: The fetch is being made inside a useAsyncData call presently (if that's an issue).

Any pointer in the right direction would be greatfully appreciated.

Comment: You can use `useRequestHeaders` composable to access the headers object and you can set `headers` option in `useFetch` (not `useAsyncData` though). I haven't tried it yet, but you should be able to 1) get the headers object, 2) delete the unwanted header, 3) pass the modified object with `useFetch` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by recognising that the call was coming from the browser on the front-end. Using Nuxt server side I created an API that made the fetch instead. Because that fetch was coming from my machine and NOT the browser, the Origin header was not sent through with the request.

I don't think it mattered but I also included mode: "no-cors" just to be sure.

I'll try removing that as I think it probably does not matter from a server side call.

@Ellrohir - I'm still going to try your suggestion, definitely still use cases for being able to do header removals :)